# How do I convert Color to Char?

Tags: c#, unicode, colors, char

I found this code to convert a Unicode character to a color, such as if the character A, it will make rgb 0 8 4. 
How would I reverse it in order to turn a color into a character, like if the rgb was 0 8 4 it would make an A?

```
        const int RedMask = 0xF8;
        const int GreenMask = 0xF8;
        const int BlueMask = 0xFC;
        const int RedShift = 8;
        const int GreenShift = 3;
        const int BlueShift = 2;

        int val = ch;
        int r = (val >> RedShift) & RedMask;
        int g = (val >> GreenShift) & GreenMask;
        int b = (val << BlueShift) & BlueMask;

        Color clr = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your char is 2 bytes long in .Net
So let's say it's 0xFFFF

```
RedMask =   0b11111000    
GreenMask = 0b11111000    
BlueMask =  0b11111100
```

Let's call most significant bit the first bit (left most)

This is how we get **Red** value

```
Right shift by 8 bits. You get  0b11111111(11111111) <-- this number in parenthesis get pushed off    
                       mask it  0b11111000
                       result   0b11111000 <-- our 1st to 5th bit are preserved
```

so we get 1st-5th bits from Red 1st-5th

This is how we get **Green** value

```
Right shift by 3 bits. You get 0b1111111111111 (111)
                       mask it 0b0000011111000
                        result 0b0000011111000 <-- That's our 6th to 10th bit.
```

Now we get 6th-10th bits from 1st-5th of Green

Lastly on **Blue**

```
Left shift by 2 bits. You get (11) 0b111111111111111100
                      mask it      0b000000000011111100
                      You get      0b000000000011111100 <-- That's the rest of the bits here :-)
```

We get 11-16th bit from green bit 1st-6th

=================================
Now we put that all together we can recompose the original value by stitching 1st-5th bits of Red to 1st-5th bits of Green, 1st-6th bits of Blue. like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            Color color = Char2Color('A');
            char ch = Color2Char(color);

        }

        static char Color2Char(Color c)
        {
            Byte[] result = {0x00,0x00};

            var red = (c.R >> 3) ;
            var green = (c.G >> 3) ;
            var blue = (c.B >> 2);

            result[0] = (byte)(red << 3);
            result[0] = (byte)(result[0] + (green >> 2));
            result[1] = (byte)(green << 6);
            result[1] = (byte)(result[1] + blue);
            Array.Reverse(result);
            return BitConverter.ToChar(result,0);
        }

        static Color Char2Color(char ch)
        {
            const int RedMask = 0xF8;
            const int GreenMask = 0xF8;
            const int BlueMask = 0xFC;
            const int RedShift = 8;
            const int GreenShift = 3;
            const int BlueShift = 2;

            int val = ch;
            int r = (val >> RedShift) & RedMask;
            int g = (val >> GreenShift) & GreenMask;
            int b = (val << BlueShift) & BlueMask;

            return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
        }

    }
}
```